# How to use python to seperate a one column CSV file if the columns have no headings, then save this into a new excel file?

Tags: python, excel, csv, spyder

So, I am quite new to python and have been googling a lot but have not found a good solution. What I am looking to do is automate text to columns using python in an excel document without headers.

Here is the excel sheet I have

[it is a CSV file where all the data is in one column without headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNTfq.png)

ex. hi ho loe time jobs barber
jim joan hello

009 00487 08234 0240 2.0348 20.34829

delimeter is space and comma

[What I want to come out is saved in another excel with the first two rows deleted and seperated into columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKUyH.png)
( this can be done using text to column in excel but i would like to automate this for several excel sheets)

009  | 00487  | 08234 |  0240 |  2.0348 |  20.34829

the code i have written so far is like this:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import csv


    path = 'C:/Users/ionan/OneDrive - Universiteit Utrecht/Desktop/UCU/test_excel'

    os.chdir(path)

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):


        for f in files:

            df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\t' + ';', engine = 'python')
```

Comment: Do you want to delete the first two rows in the original excel sheet and then split the data in remaining rows in multiple columns to give you a new excel sheet?

Comment: yes! i was not sure if splitting or deleting is better to do first, but in the end i want both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original file with name as `data.xlsx`:

[image]

This means all the data we need is under the column `Data`.

Code to split data into multiple columns for a single file:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

f = 'data.xlsx'

# -- Insert the following code in your `for f in files` loop -- 
file_data = pd.read_excel(f) 

# Since number of values to be split is not known, set the value of `num_cols` to
# number of columns you expect in the modified excel file
num_cols = 20

# Create a dataframe with twenty columns 
new_file = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["col_{}".format(i) for i in range(num_cols)])

# Change the column name of the first column in new_file to "Data"
new_file = new_file.rename(columns = {"col_0": file_data.columns[0]})

# Add the value of the first cell in the original file to the first cell of the 
# new excel file
new_file.loc[0, new_file.columns[0]] = file_data.iloc[0, 0]

# Loop through all rows of original excel file
for index, row in file_data.iterrows():

    # Skip the first row
    if index == 0:
        continue

    # Split the row by `space`. This gives us a list of strings.
    split_data = file_data.loc[index, "Data"].split(" ")
    print(split_data)

    # Convert each element to a float (a number) if we want numbers and not strings
    # split_data = [float(i) for i in split_data]

    # Make sure the size of the list matches to the number of columns in the `new_file` 
    # np.NaN represents no value. 
    split_data = [np.NaN]  + split_data + [np.NaN] * (num_cols - len(split_data) - 1)

    # Store the list at a given index using `.loc` method
    new_file.loc[index] = split_data

# Drop all the columns where there is not a single number
new_file.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)

# Get the original excel file name
new_file_name = f.split(".")[0]

# Save the new excel file at the same location where the original file is. 
new_file.to_excel(new_file_name + "_modified.xlsx", index=False)
```

This creates a new excel file (with a single sheet) of name `data_modified.xlsx`:

[image]

**Summary (code without comments)**:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

f = 'data.xlsx'

file_data = pd.read_excel(f) 

num_cols = 20
new_file = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["col_{}".format(i) for i in range(num_cols)])
new_file = new_file.rename(columns = {"col_0": file_data.columns[0]})
new_file.loc[0, new_file.columns[0]] = file_data.iloc[0, 0]

for index, row in file_data.iterrows():

    if index == 0:
        continue

    split_data = file_data.loc[index, "Data"].split(" ")
    split_data = [np.NaN]  + split_data + [np.NaN] * (num_cols - len(split_data) - 1)
    new_file.loc[index] = split_data

new_file.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
new_file_name = f.split(".")[0]
new_file.to_excel(new_file_name + "_modified.xlsx", index=False)
```